# How to prevent double array translated as a list of element in string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

In `react/redux-form` based web application, I have a variable `const list` refers to `double array` in the program. If I print it out via `console.log`, this is what I see.

```
(2) [Array(1), Array(1)]
0: Array(1)
    0: (2) ["aaa", "bbb"]
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
1: Array(1)
    1: (2) ["ccc", "ddd"]
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

I need to insert that variable inside of string like this.

```
const retVal = `{ 'type': 'something', 'foo': ${list} }`;
```

When I inspect `retVal` from `redux > State > Tree > form` via `devTool` in `chrome`, it is printed as following for `foo`.

```
 'foo': aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd
```

Is there way that I can translate as this instead?

```
'foo': [ ["aaa", "bbb"], ["ccc", "ddd"] ]
```

Comment: Try with `'foo': ${JSON.stringify(list)}`

Comment: What does your reducer that adds it to the state look like?

Comment: @Shidersz, Ty! ${JSON.stringify(list)} worked for me.